# Can you identify this time-travel/alternate history novel?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, alternate-history

I read this sometime in the 2000s, in another state, so I can't go back and check the shelves.

A scientist discovers time-travel, or something like it -- it's a time-sea. Swimming in it causes ripples or waves that change the timeline. More and more time-changed civilizations enter the sea to battle. The swimmers have tails, the length which represents their life-span or memories? Chop off the tail, and they remember less. The best warrior is one with a super-short tail and hardly any memories.

It was definitely a novel, and not a short story in a collection. Beyond that -- no idea of author, title, or even the cover. Except that I read it in hard-cover, so not a straight-to-mass-market pulp.

Comment: same answer, but left off the alternate history and the "tails" -- those were the two things I really remembered as setting the book apart from others in the genre. The other question focused on a plot element. Could these be merged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet-another-search for keywords brought me to Google books (thanks, Google!) and ultimately to [Richard Garfinkle's *All of an Instant*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312872607).